# Firebase Functions Not Sending Notification To Device

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I have some code in my Firebase Function which puts together a notification and sends it to the user's device. 
But after it sends one notification to a token, and it gets delivered, the future notifications it sends don't go through. I know it is not the client side, all I do is print out the data. This is how I send the notification:

```
    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(recipientToken, payload)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error sending message. Cause: ", error);
    });
```

Am I missing some sort of parameter or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
 const options = {
    priority: "high",
};
```

And and putting it here:

```
  admin.messaging().sendToDevice(recipientToken, payload, options)
.then(function (response) {
    console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error sending message. Cause: ", error);
});
```

I had the same problem a while ago, so I hope this helps.

Comment: It's sending notifications every time now! Thanks!